# Datepicker is not working with jQuery Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I am trying to get datepicker for my HTML `text` element But it's Not Working For me,
Thanks.

used js Files

`

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.dimensions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.accordion.js"></script>
```

`

even i used
`<script> $.noConflict();</script>`

code-

```
$(document).ready(function()
  {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
 });
```

Comment: provide some code mate..

Comment: Check web browser console, provide code which you use to trigger the datepicker.

Comment: With Wordpress, you're better off adding these scripts via `functions.php` as jQuery UI is packaged into Wordpress, you just have to initialise it. Secondly - use `jQuery` instead of `$`. Lastly, add your *error* messages.

Comment: Mackiee, i tried using that also

Comment: are you trying to retirve the date value from a text field..??

Comment: yes retriving it's done, problem is only datepicker not displaying

Comment: do u have any console errors..??

Comment: provide your html tag which has the class `'.datepicker'`

Comment: @Reena You might as well delete this question then.

Answer (score 1):

### functions.php

```
function loadjQueryUi() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-accordion');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'loadjQueryUi' );
```

### scripts.js

```
<script>
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('#accordion').accordion({
            create: function() {
                jQuery('.datepicker').datepicker({
                   dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

### front-end.php

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Start Date</h3>
  <div>
      <input type="text" class="datepicker" placeholder="Pick a start date" />
  </div>
</div>
```

if you still much prefer to use the `noConflict()` (which is already called in WordPress'es `.jquery` file)

### with noConflict wrapping

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#accordion').accordion({
            create: function() {
                $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                   dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```